# Gmail: This message seems dangerous

Tags: gmail

I am working on an invite system for my work, the invite system sends an email to the recipient with a link containing a unique token allowing them to sign up.

The issue is, now that I am actually testing it, the emails are marked as "This message seems dangerous" by Gmail, This looks really bad for the company. I have not been able to find any information on what triggers this.

[image: error message]

The email is being sent via office365(SMTP) as that is what our email is set up with to try and avoid this kind of thing.

I have seen comments online that it may be due to the token link, If so, how else am I meant to do this?

Comment: This comes when you do spamming, means sent a lot of emails with a fixed duration like within one day or within 2 hours etc. Click on _Looks safe_ and proceed.

Comment: @serenesat Thats not it, This is 1 about 15 emails sent out in total today, the 1st of 2 sent to gmail address, all the rest were sent to an exchange mail server. Looking through the logs, these 2 emails are the only ones send in the last couple of weeks to a gmail address.

Me getting the message is not the problem, I can't have other users getting this message as it makes it look like we are phishing or sending out a virus or something.

Comment: Google consider such things as spam and warn people when email are being sent through any automation/boat method without paid service.

Comment: @serenesat What kind of paid service am I supposed to use? Office365 IS a paid service.

We have not had any problem in the past sending out notification style emails (send in the exact same manner) with the same template, just different core text and no token link (think of this as a forgot password email)

Comment: Please read [Prevent mail to Gmail users from being blocked or sent to spam](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reworded the email to 'Complete Registration' instead of 'You have been invited' with the body similarly changed. The people receiving this email should know it is coming and if not (the person hitting send may have forgot to let them know first) there is a brief description of why they got it and who to contact if they are confused.

It has seemed to work, I have sent a few test emails to different gmail address' and have not yet seen the issue since the change. Hope this helps anyone else facing the same issue. It seems to be in the wording. I guess 'You have been invited' probably triggers some sort of scam/pyramid scheme flag.